# css locator builder in Selenium IDE doesn't get first ID

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-ide

Let's say that I have some html like:

```
<div id="container1" class="wrap">
    <div class="somestyle">first content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container2" class="wrap">
    <div class="somestyle">second content
    </div>
</div>
   .
   .
   .
<div id="containern" class="wrap">
    <div class="somestyle">nth content
    </div>
</div>
```

Recording tests with Selenium IDE, ID and CSS locator builders in the top, 
if I click on "first content" I get something like:

```
css=div.somestyle
```

on the other hand, if I click on any other content starting from the second, I get (what I want):

```
css=#container2 > div.somestyle,
   .
   .
   .
css=#containern > div.somestyle
```

The only exception is the first element.

Why is that? Is it a bug? How can I avoid, without having to rewrite the whole HTML structure?

Comment: Does clicking second content give you `css=#container2 > div.somestyle`?

Comment: Yes, it does: the only exception is the first element. 
For each of the other, I get the full "breadcrumb style" css selector.
I will edit the question to specify it.

Comment: I don't think this is a BUG/Problems, juz maybe the IDE default record ur selection by css class.. u may try and change the selection criteria by using ID perhaps..

Comment: @cL83: That it's clearly written in my question: "ID and CSS locator builders in the top"; but thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you want to prioritize the css as first choice in Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1):

As class for all three container is same, so to identify it records like that.It is not but.
 for eg. If you have three check box with same name then it will record

```
click  | name=vehicle
click  | xpath=(//input[@name='vehicle'])[2]
click  | xpath=(//input[@name='vehicle'])[3]
```

In you code, class is same for all container.

So to identify container IDE code will display like you mentioned.
For first it will display directly, will consider as first entry.

```
css=div.somestyle
```

And for next entries will go like

```
css=#container2 > div.somestyle,
   .
   .
   .
css=#containern > div.somestyle
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: you can write your code manually, here you can use div ID as it is unique for each block.

Comment: Writing the tests manually is what I wanted to avoid.
I am willing to create a custom locator builder, though.